# webservice frameworks / apps for sending work to helper servers?

Tags: windows, web-services, webservice-client

i'm not sure how to even phrase this problem in a way to do google searches, so hope you can help out.

Say I have a web app, and when a customer places a purchase, I want to send a message to a windows server to build a custom installer,  then send the customer a link to download the resulting app.

Are there any open source projects that solve this kind of server-to-server interop issue?      I'd like to not recreate the wheel on this if possible :(

i prefer soemthing in either C# or python, but ANY directional assistance would be great

Comment: Have you looked at MSMQ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing It's an alternative to using web services.

Comment: i have a python web app (running on a 3rd party host), so i need to communicate to/from that,  from what i remember about MSMQ, it's windows-server ecosystem specific

Comment: I figured since you mentioned C# ... what about ActiveMQ/ZeroMQ/RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm just going to use pubnub, which basically does what i need.